# How to set kubernetes secrets to json object

Tags: node.js, firebase, kubernetes, firebase-admin

I'm currently building an API for Firebase Admin SDK and I want to store the Admin SDK credential file as a secret in Kubernetes.

This is an example from google on how to use the credential file:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://test.firebaseio.com"
});
```

the credentials are in serviceAccountKey.json.

this is what the content of the file looks like:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "test",
  "private_key_id": "3455dj555599993n5d425j878999339393po6",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\lkjsfdjlsjfsjflksjfklsjkljklfsjfksjkdjskljflk;sjflskjfklsjdljhijshdkjfhsjfhjsb2223b3==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "123334444555556665478884",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk%40test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

I already have this file I use for my other secrets:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: paisecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
    MONGODB_PASSWORD: "sjldkjsjdfklsl"
    MONGODB_USERNAME: "prod_user"
    MONGODB_HOST: "test.azure.mongodb.net"
```

I'll like to add `serviceAccountKey.json` or its content to the secret file above and if possible I'll like to access it within the API like this: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is just how to include it as a string in the Secret, you could simply add it as a multiline string.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: paisecret
type: Opaque
stringData:
    MONGODB_PASSWORD: "sjldkjsjdfklsl"
    MONGODB_USERNAME: "prod_user"
    MONGODB_HOST: "test.azure.mongodb.net"
    FIREBASE_ADMIN: >
      {
        "type": "service_account",
        "project_id": "test",
        "private_key_id": "3455dj555599993n5d425j878999339393po6",
        "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\lkjsfdjlsjfsjflksjfklsjkljklfsjfksjkdjskljflk;sjflskjfklsjdljhijshdkjfhsjfhjsb2223b3==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
        "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk@test.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
        "client_id": "123334444555556665478884",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk%40test.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
      }
```